# How can I get my third party script to correctly function on my website?

Tags: html, plugins

When the user fills out my form and clicks on the button “Generate CV”. The HTML form should automatically download as a PDF to the users download folder.

**Problem one:**

I tried using [this](https://www.pdfmyform.com/how-it-works/) third party plugin but can't get it to function correctly as when I click on the `<a class"btn btn-circle btn-outline-brand" onclick="pdfmyform(this);" href="#">Generate CV</a>` button nothing happens. How can I get this to work?

[Inspect errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfgq6.jpg)

**Problem two:**

How can I get this button `<a class"btn btn-circle btn-outline-brand" onclick="pdfmyform(this);" href="#">Generate CV</a>` to look like `<input class="btn btn-circle btn-outline-brand" type="submit" value="Generate CV">` I did use the same class. However, I think that class information in bootstrap only applies to the `<input>` tag so how can I get around this issue?

**Below is my current code**

```
     <!-- Form-->
     <section class="module bg-gray text-center divider-bottom p-3">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                 <form id="contact-form" method="post" novalidate>
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name (Click Me)" required="">
                             <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail (Click Me)" required="">
                             <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Mobile Number (Click Me)" required="">
                             <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Education History (Click Me)" rows="12" required=""></textarea>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Previous Employers (Click Me)" rows="12" required=""></textarea>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                             <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Personal Skills / Hobbies (Click Me)" rows="12" required=""></textarea>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-12">
                          <p></p>
                          <div class="text-center">
                             <input class="btn btn-circle btn-outline-brand" type="submit" value="Generate CV">
                             <a class"btn btn-circle btn-outline-brand" onclick="pdfmyform(this);" href="#">Generate CV</a>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </form>
                 <!-- Ajax response-->
                 <div class="ajax-response text-center" id="contact-response"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </section>
     <!-- Form end-->
```

Here is the location of where I put the third party script.

```
      <!-- Scripts-->
      <script src="assets/js/custom/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/custom/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/custom/plugins.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pdfmyform.com/js/pdfmyform.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/custom/custom.min.js"></script>
</html>
</body>
```

FULL WEBPAGE CODE BELOW IF REQUIRED

```
 <!-- Form-->
         <section class="module bg-gray text-center divider-bottom p-3">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <form id="contact-form" method="post" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name (Click Me)" required="">
                                 <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail (Click Me)" required="">
                                 <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Mobile Number (Click Me)" required="">
                                 <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Education History (Click Me)" rows="12" required=""></textarea>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Previous Employers (Click Me)" rows="12" required=""></textarea>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Personal Skills / Hobbies (Click Me)" rows="12" required=""></textarea>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                              <p></p>
                              <div class="text-center">
                                 <input class="btn btn-circle btn-outline-brand" type="submit" value="Generate CV">
                                 <a class"btn btn-circle btn-outline-brand" onclick="pdfmyform(this);" href="#">PDF this page!</a>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                     <!-- Ajax response-->
                     <div class="ajax-response text-center" id="contact-response"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </section>
         <!-- Form end-->

      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center text-black py-3">© Copyright 2018 Handcrafted By Zeplur. All Rights Reserved |
         <a href="terms.pdf">Terms and conditions</a>
      </div>
      <!-- To top button--><a class="scroll-top" href="#top"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
      <!-- Scripts-->
      <script src="assets/js/custom/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/custom/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/custom/plugins.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pdfmyform.com/js/pdfmyform.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/custom/custom.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just want to point out that all your lib should be placed before your custom js. So, <script src="assets/js/custom/plugins.min.js"></script><script src="assets/js/custom/custom.min.js"></script> Would come after pdfmyform.js declaration

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error in inspect view of browser?

Comment: Ok thanks I'll update that now and see if it works. @RaviKumarGupta Inspect errors > https://imgur.com/a/xv5FlPJ  Could it be because, I'm hosting the files locally at the moment?

Comment: Can someone assist please?

Comment: I suppose you need to host things properly. You can make a local server and host the content there. Then all of the scripts should work.

Comment: In the image you can see that because of security, pdfform is not allowed to read content locally. Also cross-origin will also not work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is fine. But as you can see in the inspect view, errors clearly say that the local resources can not be loaded.

Problem 1 - `pdfmyform()` is not allowed to read local resources.

Once you host the code with a proper website or a local web(http) server, this should work fine.